# Refer to css in root style library in master page - only root

Tags: master-page, css

How do I add a css that are located in root style library in a master page?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~Site/Style Library/awesome.css%>" runat="server" After="SharepointCssFile" />
```

**Has to work beteween site collections...**

Look at @atish answer.. also see this link [cssregistration](http://thomasdaly.net/2012/05/02/sharepoint-cssregistration-or-link/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `~sitecollection` instead of `~Site`

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/awesome.css %>" runat="server"  />
```

For html master page, it will be:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/awesome.css %>" runat="server"  />-->
```

Comment: Hmm that was the first thing I tried, probably a deploy that didnt go as expected. Thnx @atish

Comment: @Plexus81 I think your problem is "After="SharepointCssFile".

Comment: It should work. I have used it in several projects. above code I just copy/paste. Check everything properly @Plexus81

Comment: @Plexus81 it could as well be a missing space and the end of .css "~Site/Style Library/awesome.css%>" 

But Atish answer about changing from site to sitecollection is the correct way to have it working for root sites as well as "Sub" site collections.

Comment: @Christoffer can't I use the after property?

Comment: @Plexus81 Of course you can, but should it not refer to a actual .CSS file? :)

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74508/cssregistration-after-property-with-custom-stylesheet